# Adding a route to make server directly accessible over VPN, for specific subnet?

Tags: iptables, openvpn, route

I have a Linux machine on a segregated network that I VPN into. When I VPN in, I get assigned a virtual IP by the VPN server like 192.168.251.x

I've found that when I VPN in, I can RDP to Windows boxes no problem. Ping, http, rdp, etc.. all work. However, the Linux box is not immediately accessible. In fact, I have to first RDP onto a machine already on that segregated network, and then I can ssh into the Linux box.

This tells me the Linux box is only accepting traffic from devices already on its native subnet, and that I need to tell it to accept traffic from the virtual VPN subnet from which external devices will be originating.

I've tried this rule:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.251.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Where 192.168.251.0/24 is the virtual VPN subnet. But I still cannot ping the Linux box yet from my connected host machine. So either I added the wrong rule, or added it incorrectly. Any tips/guidance?

```
user@HOST:~> uname -a 
Linux HOST 3.0.51-0.7.9-default #1 SMP Thu Nov 29 22:12:17 UTC 2012 (f3be9d0) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

user@HOST:~> cat /proc/version Linux 
version 3.0.51-0.7.9-default (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973] (SUSE Linux) ) #1 SMP Thu Nov 29 22:12:17 UTC 2012 (f3be9d0)
```

Am I adding the wrong rule, or missing a rule?

EDIT:

My current iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.251.0/24     anywhere            ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
```

Also, a packet capture of icmp and http/s traffic shows traffic from my VPN client going to the Linux machine, but never any return traffic from the Linux machine. Not even a reply with "invalid XXX" or anything. This indicates that traffic is getting dropped if I'm not mistaken.

EDIT:

```
user@HOST:~> ip route sh
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope link
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link
192.168.20.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.20.219

user@HOST:~> sudo iptables --list
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.251.0/24    ctstate ESTABLISHED
```

EDIT:

Solution for me was to run:

```
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.20.1
```

Then I was able to ping and telnet to the box directly via VPN.

Comment: Can you look at logs on the Linux box?  Run a sniffer (e.g., `tcpdump` or Wireshark) on it to determine what network traffic it is seeing?

Comment: Yep. Did a capture and interestingly I can only see traffic going 1 way. From my VPN ip to the linux machine. I see all 4 of my icmp packets, and my https requests. But nothing ever comes back from the linux machine. I know it's not a firewall rule because traffic to other machines on the network makes it through just fine. It's like this machine is blocking/dropping/rejecting my traffic entirely.

Comment: Sounds like a routing issue on your Linux box. Does it know where to send the return packets back to your client? `ip route sh` could help debug this.

Comment: I'm almost certain it's a routing issue. I wasn't sure however if I needed to define an outbound rule as well.So I added an outbound rule in iptables too. Updated the ticket with requested information.

Comment: Actually, my bad. I did read it wrong. There is nothing about the 192.168.251.x subnet. The subnet listed from the command (192.168.20.0/24) is the native subnet. Not the VPN one. So it doesn't actually have anything regarding the VPN subnet.

Comment: Yeah, you should probably just add the same default route to your Linux box, that you already have on your Windows boxes (e.g `ip route add default via 192.168.20.1`)

Comment: [user234931](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/234931/user234931) That did the trick! Thanks a ton. If you write an answer I will accept that as a the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Linux box is dropping the return packet since it has no valid route back to the VPN network.

Assuming your gateway is at `192.168.20.1`, adding this as a default route on your Linux box will likely resolve your issue:

```
ip route add default via 192.168.20.1
```